# How can I remove 1 user name remember in IE

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, user-profiles, internet-explorer-6

I am using IE 6 on Windows XP. IE remembers my 4 of my login names to my google account.
Is it possible for me to just remove 1 login name and password that remembered by IE and keep the rest in tact?

I tried searching the login name i want to remove in the registry, but it does not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often things remembered in autofill dropdowns can be removed by double-clicking the input field or typing a letter to make the browser show the list, and then use the cursor keys to go down in the list and highlight it. Next, depending on the browser and operating system, hit something like Delete, or Shift-Delete, or Command-Delete, or Shift-Backspace to remove it from the list.

I also *assume* IE6 has some settings in Tools, Internet Options that is related to remembering user names and passwords. Next to that option you'll find a button to show you what has been remembered. But IE6 being so old, I doubt anyone can give you the exact location to that option.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the IE 6 index.dat file with the [PCPlex tool](http://pcplex.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/file-opener.php?ext=DAT&tid=fileext-1000004-msn). There is a [good article on the PurgeIE](http://www.purgeie.com/indexdat.htm) website describing how the index.dat file works with auto-complete.